# MVC Validate only 1 model from 2 (or multiple) models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, model-validation

Now, my scenario is I want to validate **Contact** model (Secondary) only if ContactID > 0 otherwise it will validate **Organization** model (Primary) only. I don't want to write custom business validations for this.

Please suggest me if it is possible in MVC structure with Data Annotations. I have refer one model inside another model like below

```
public class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {
        this.OrgStatus = "Active";
        this.OrgContact = new Contact();
    }
    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Organization Code is required")]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string OrgCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is required")]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string OrgStatus { get; set; }

    public Contact OrgContact { get; set; }

}

public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        this.Title = "Mr.";
    }

    [Required]
    public int? ContactID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Title", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter First Name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Middle Name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Last Name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When you say you don't want to write custom business validations, what do you mean?

Comment: means by writing code like normally using if else then I can write it...but such things solve my one model's need only...I am looking for one universal solution.

Comment: Write your validation code by writing a helper method.  One of the parameters should be your viewmodel and another be your modelstate so that you can add errors to it.  By doing this you make your validation code reusable.

Comment: Can you pls explain it with any example...

Comment: I have added an answer that uses inheritence to allow you to make use of the validation attributes that you have already decorated your models with.  I get the impression that you are concerned with repeating yourself, so this should solve that issue.  The final result is that you have two models to bind to - one with the Contact property and one without but by making use of the same validation attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of telling MVC to just ignore the validation attributes on a nested model (in your case `Contact`) without employing the use of a custom model binder.  MVC will automatically execute the validation rules for any nested models.

---

### Inheritence

If the problem is that you would like to make use of the *same* view models with the validation attributes, but the nested `Contact` property is only appropriate to receive the posted values on certain pages, then you can use inheritence to create a view model that includes the `Contact` property and one that doesn't.

In this example you might have two action methods, one that accepts a view model that does have a `Contact` property and one that doesn't.

```
// Example action methods
public ActionResult Page1(Organization requestModel)
{
    ...
}

public ActionResult Page2(OrganizationWithContact requestModel)
{
    ...
}
```

You can remove the `Contact` property from your `Organization` model and make use of inheritence to ensure that you have a model specific to the page that posts the `Contact` values and one that doesn't.

```
public class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {
        this.OrgStatus = "Active";
        this.OrgContact = new Contact();
    }

    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Organization Code is required")]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string OrgCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is required")]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string OrgStatus { get; set; }

    // No longer required here.
    // public Contact OrgContact { get; set; }
}

// New model, using inheritence to include `Contact` model
public class OrganizationWithContact : Organization
{
    public Contact OrgContact { get; set; }
}
```

By using the above model layout, you are repeating the use of your existing validation attributes.

Comment: Hi Ishan.  Sadly there is no way to do this without writing business logic that will validate your model.  This validation can certainly be reusable though!  I can give you an example on how you would achieve this if you want?